# What's the goal of @Lob annotation in Hibernate ? Why only mapping to a string is not sufficient?

Tags: hibernate, orm, mapping, blob

In my database, I've got some columns mapped with a BLOB or CLOB type.

When mapping such a field, hibernate recommends :

```
@Lob
public String getBlobField() { ... }
```

Why do we need the @Lob annotation ?

Comment: You refer my link. If you still have any doubts let me know.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950938/proper-hibernate-mapping-for-lob-in-hibernate-pojo-we-are-using-hibernate-mapp